# Use of a function using **kwargs

Tags: python

In my exercise, i have to use `**kwargs` to print the arguments entered in my function in alphabetical order.

Here is what I have for now:

```
def afficher(**kwargs):
if kwargs is not None:
    for i in kwargs:
        print (i)

afficher(helpme=7,plz=10)
```

returns:

```
plz
helpme
```

My concern is:

- I'd like them returned in alphabetical order
- I'd like them returned as:

  helpme = 7

  plz = 10

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Plain dictionaries are not sorted, as their keys are hashed and end up stored accordingly.

In your case you can scan the sorted keys of the `kwargs` dictionary

```
for i in sorted(kwargs):
```

So the code becomes

```
def afficher(**kwargs):
    for i in sorted(kwargs):
        print ('{}={}'.format(i,kwargs[i]))

afficher(helpme=7,plz=10)
```

which always produces

```
helpme=7
plz=10
```

Note: as you can see, I have removed the `if`, that I presume you inserted to check if any keyword arguments were passed to the function.
In such case `kwargs` will be an empty dictionary `{}`, not `None`, so there is no need to prevent the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `**something` as a function argument, inside the function body `something` will be a `dict` that maps the keywords to their values.

To iterate over the sorted keys you would do:

```
def afficher(**kwargs):
    for k,v in sorted(kwargs.items()):
        print '{}={}'.format(k,v)
```

Note that when no keyword arguments are passed, `kwargs={}` and `kwards.items()=[]`. The `for` loop will exit immediately, so there is no reason to check it. Also, you wouldn't check it with `if kwargs is None` since `{}` is not `None`. You would check it with `{}`.

Comment: I am sure I've seen a similar answer before.. ;) The explanation of the packing of the keyword arguments is very vague and incorrect. Also, be aware that `blank` is not `None`.

Comment: Yeah, our answers were posted at almost the same time (or maybe I had the tab open for a few minutes). I like iterating over `.items()` better, which is why I haven't deleted my answer. I have edited some of my wording to address your comment.

Comment: No problem whatsoever, I just pointed out a few things to allow you to expound the subject better